# Finding maximum and minimum of list of lists using dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum value within a list of lists. To elaborate, I have this variable which stores tweets:

```
lines = [['ladybug7501',
  'RT SamaritansPurse: You can help the many across #PuertoRico who remain in desperate need after #HurricaneMaria. See how here: …',
  'Negative',
  -1],
 ['DyEliana',
  'RT daddy_yankee: La madre naturaleza está azotando con potencia a sus hijos. Mi corazón y mis oraciones con mi tierra #PuertoRico y mis he…',
  'Neutral',
  0],
 ['waffloesH',
  'RT SteveCase: PLEASE HELP: ChefJoseAndres is working tirelessly to feed #PuertoRico, but urgently needs our help: ',
  'Neutral',
  0],
 ['SteveLevinePR',
  'RT StarrMSS: .elvisduran gave 30K to @Bethenny to charter  plane to bring supplies to #PuertoRico HurricaneMaria. He also gave 100K to ',
  'Neutral',
  0],
 ['bronxdems',
  'RT theCEI: THANK YOU to rubendiazjr and the NY Hispanic Clergy for organizing an amazing event last week in support of PuertoRico! ❤️…',
  'Positive',
  3]]
```

It has a lot more lists but I only posted a sample. I've done most of the grunt work to get to this point. What I'm trying to do is print out the tweet which has the highest positive words and the highest negative. The higher the number on the last slice of the list, the more positive it is. (The -1, 0, and 3). I'm trying to print out the tweet which has the highest value associated with it.

This is some code I've been playing around with:

```
user_lines = []
for line in lines:
    freqs  = {}
    user_lines.append(line[2])
    for i in user_lines:
        if i not in freqs:
            freqs[i] = 1
        else:
            freqs[i] += 1
        
freqs
```

But that's all I have. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You want frequency of words occurring in each tweet?

Comment: No, I do not. As I said, I'm playing around with it. I just want to be able to print out the tweet which has the highest number of positive words and the lowest based on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it by specifying the key of `max` and `min`

```
mini=min(lines, key=lambda x: x[-1])
maxi=max(lines, key=lambda x: x[-1])

print(mini)
print(maxi)
```

Output:

```
mini
['ladybug7501', 'RT SamaritansPurse: You can help the many across #PuertoRico who remain in desperate need after #HurricaneMaria. See how here: …', 'Negative', -1]

maxi
['bronxdems', 'RT theCEI: THANK YOU to rubendiazjr and the NY Hispanic Clergy for organizing an amazing event last week in support of PuertoRico! ❤️…', 'Positive', 3]
```

Comment: Thank you @MrNobody33! That did the trick. Might I pry you for one more assistance? I want to be able to print out the screen name of the user who has the most positive tweets and negative tweets. In others words, [['ladybug7501', 'Positive'], ['brutus', 'Positive'], ['ladybug7501', 'Positive']] for example. ladybug7501 would be the user with the most positive tweets. How would I do that given your code?

Comment: Sure. Try [this](https://pastebin.com/zJJme0vR) with `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Your code works. How do I try that on my variable?                                                                  lines = [['ladybug7501',
  'RT SamaritansPurse: You can help the many across #PuertoRico who remain in desperate need after #HurricaneMaria. See how here: …',
  'Negative',
  -1]]

Comment: you just have to change the index where positive is going to be. In the code i gave you was at index 1, with this case, I guess it´s at index -2 @runner16 .

Comment: I see what you mean now @MrNobody33. That worked! I should have experimented more with the indexes. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save **only** the worst and the best rated tweet in a dictionary, you could `iterate` through the tweets and save the index where the worst/best rating is placed. After that you could save the informations of these indices into a dictionary like this:

```
highest = 0
lowest = 0
dic = {}
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    number_of_likes = line[3]
    if number_of_likes < lowest:
        lowest = i
    if number_of_likes > highest:
        highest = i

dic['lowest'] = [lines[lowest][3], lines[lowest][1]]
dic['highest'] = [lines[highest][3], lines[highest][1]]
```

output:

```
{'lowest': [-1, 'RT SamaritansPurse: You can help the many across #PuertoRico who remain in desperate need after #HurricaneMaria. See how here: …'], 'highest': [3, 'RT theCEI: THANK YOU to rubendiazjr and the NY Hispanic Clergy for organizing an amazing event last week in support of PuertoRico! ❤️…']}
```